# Binding ItemSource of an element in a UserControl to an item in the parents ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls, itemssource

Sorry, I'm thrashing around a bit learning MVVM, WPF, and XAML simultaneously.

I have a problem that I created and I am completely confused with how this should be handled in MVVM.

What I have is a parent window that contains a user control that draws graphs.  The graph drawing XAML used to be part of the parent window, but I moved it to a user control for organization as the parent window was very big.

In the parent windows XAML I have .....

```
<Window ....>
     <Window.Resources>
         <ViewModel:DropGraphViewModel x:Key="myViewModel"/>
     </Window.Resources>

     <!-- Set the data context to the view model. -->
     <Window.DataContext>
         <Binding Source="{StaticResource myViewModel}"/>
     </Window.DataContext>
     .....
</Window>
```

And then in the new user control XAML class I have a resource that is created that is a 'generator' class that serves up things that will be used by parts of the graph.  It looks like this...

```
<UserControl ......
    <!-- Graph resources -->
        <Grid.Resources>
            <!-- The binding here for ItemsSource represents the collection the graph will be bound to -->

            <!-- THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK ANYMORE  -->
            <Graphs:LineChartGenerator x:Key="generator" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, Path=SampleData}" Width="500"  Height="200"> -->
        </Grid.Resources>
```

And then later on when I want to do some things like draw graph lines I used to reference the generator through binding.

```
    <!-- Connect the points -->
    <Polyline Points="{Binding Source={StaticResource generator}, Path=Points}" Stroke="Blue" />
```

What is now broken now that I am in am using a nested user control is that when I create the instance of the 'generator' class in the resources, I can't pass in the binding that was **ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, Path=SampleData}"** because I no longer have access to the view model (myViewModel) that is in the static resource of the parent window!  So I can't set the binding during the creation time of the resource like I used to do.

**What is the proper MVVM way to handle this type of pattern?**

How do I inject the ItemsSource into my new user control so that it can pass it in when it creates the LineChartGenerator class instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `DataContext` is an inheritable `DependencyProperty` which means it trickles down the visual hierarchy.
2. Resources are not part of visual tree until they are hosted.

So in your case, your `Graphs:LineChartGenerator` has to be hosted in your `UserControl` and not delcared in the Resource section. Once you do that it acquires its own `DataContext` from the parent `Window`, this way as @GazTheDestroyer, pointed out you only need a implicit binding `ItemsSource="{Binding SampleData}"`

Comment: You say, @AngelWPF, it has to be hosted in my UserControl, but this is a simple class derived from DependencyObject. Can I host it if it isn't a visual element? It's a class that hands back visual elements....

Comment: Ah, I could never get my resource to bind to the data context.  I made it a FrameworkElement and put it directly in the grid and now it can inherit the data context.  I am guessing that is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting your ViewModel to be the `DataContext` of the outer `Window`, it will also be the `DataContext` of your `UserControl`, so you should be able to access it with a simple:

```
<Graphs:LineChartGenerator x:Key="generator" ItemsSource="{Binding SampleData}" Width="500"  Height="200">
```